# Swift: RxSwift's asObservable() method and type erasure

Tags: swift3, type-erasure, rx-swift

I am having problem understanding the rationale and purpose for [asObservable method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observable.swift#L26) in RxSwift's [Observable class](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observable.swift#L12).

```
/// A type-erased `ObservableType`. 
///
/// It represents a push style sequence.
public class Observable<Element> : ObservableType {
    /// Type of elements in sequence.
    public typealias E = Element

    public func subscribe<O: ObserverType>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
        abstractMethod()
    }

    public func asObservable() -> Observable<E> {
        return self
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of asObservable when it's returning self?

Surely if you can run this method, you already have access to the object. Also, what does the "type-erased `ObservableType`" in the comment means?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is apparent if you look at the `ObservableType` protocol and what objects conform to it (namely things like subjects, etc.). 
The only guarantee is that the object will return an `Observable` in response to a call to `asObservable`. While conformance is trivial for an `Observable`, it may be less so for subjects and other units. But this guarantee allows you to use all type that can provide an `Observable` together in the same operator chain.

In essence this is similar to `String`s conformance to `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: Why does the comment say it's type erased? Is the type for this really erased?

Comment: I agree that the comment can be confusing. However I read it to mean that the type of the `ObservableType` (e.g. a `PublishSubject`) is being erased, not the type of the `Element`.

Answer (score 3):

You asked two questions:

**1. What's the purpose of asObservable when it's returning self?**

You almost don't need to ever use `asObservable()`. The only time I think you'd need is when you're assigning casting a Subject/Relay to an Observable.

Suppose you have a variable that is a `BehaviorRelay`. It can both, observe and be an observable.
**ViewModel.swift**

```
let deviceOrientation = BehaviorRelay<UIInterfaceOrientation>(value: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)
```

And then you have a variable that is not both but **only** an observable like below.

**ViewController.swift**

```
lazy var incorrect : Observable<UIInterfaceOrientation> = {
        return self.viewModel.deviceOrientation // ERROR
}()

lazy var correct : Observable<UIInterfaceOrientation> = {
        return self.viewModel.deviceOrientation.asObservable()
}()
```

Then you'd need to *cast* so you'd have the correct type.

The incorrect variable would give the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type `BehaviorRelay<UIInterfaceOrientation>`
>   to closure result type `Observable<UIInterfaceOrientation>`

**2. What does the "type-erased ObservableType" in the comment means?**

I suspect [Scott's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002153/swift-rxswifts-asobservable-method-and-type-erasure/55615920#comment71328458_42032531) is semi-correct. I mean for sure it's confusing. You can flatten the type of a `BehvaiorRelay`, `PublishSubject` to a `Observable` and then assign one Observable to another. Otherwise still they all require the associatedType to be given ie no type erasure happening.

```
let x : AnyHashable = 10
let y : AnyHashable = "Alex"

if x == y { print("equal" } // compiles!

var i = PublishSubject<Int>().asObservable()
var s = PublishSubject<String>().asObservable()

if i == s { print("equal" } // does NOT compile. Gives following error:
```

> Binary operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type
>   `Observable<Int>` and `Observable<String>`

Answer (score 0):

asObservable is simply a downcast operator used as a convenience against Relays or Subjects for operators that act on Obserables.

Here's an example of this using the RxSwift example project. If we look at this code:

```
let usernameValid = usernameOutlet.rx.text.orEmpty
            .map { $0.count >= minimalUsernameLength }
            .share(replay: 1)
```

We see that we need `.share(replay: 1)` to prevent every subscription from creating a new Observer.

We can substitue this with a `Driver` which both is shared and calls back on the main thread like this:

```
let usernameValid = usernameOutlet.rx.text.orEmpty
            .asDriver()
            .map { $0.count >= minimalUsernameLength }
```

However we cannot use `usernameValid` in for example `Observable.combineLatest` as this expects an `ObserverType` as an argument. But this driver sequence shows a type of `SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, Bool>`! To use it we have to downcast back to an `ObserverType`. We use `asObserver()` to accomplish this.

If we are already an `ObservableType` casting it does nothing. A lot of times you see this in code and it does nothing.

So we could re-write this code like:

```
let usernameValid = usernameOutlet.rx.text.orEmpty
            .asDriver()
            .map { $0.count >= minimalUsernameLength }
            .asObservable()
```

Now it returns something we can use everywhere: `Observable<Bool>`.